# How to you select percentiles of Categorical distribution in numpy or Pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have network which outputs, (9 different) equally spaced categorical distributions (basically  a Tensor of size [batch_size,9,support]).

I want to find an easy way to find percentiles, but I am not sure how to do that. I know I can compute the cdf using `torch.cumsum(dim=-1)`, but I am not sure I know how to extract the indices after that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: As an example say I have the following, which can be interpreted as 64*9 discrete distributions. I want to find the percentiles of these distributions.

```
dists=F.softmax(torch.randn(64,9,51),dim=-1)
support=torch.linspace(-1,1,51) #or any other equally spaced support
```

Comment: Would it be possible to edit your question and provide a [Minimum, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?